# Django datetimeinput widget - validate as datetime, but convert to unix time before saving

Tags: django, validation, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django form that looks like this:

```
class AnnouncementCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['publish_datetime'].widget = forms.DateTimeInput()
        self.fields['publish_datetime'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'})
        self.fields['publish_datetime'].required=False
        self.fields['document'].required=False

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyAnnouncement
        exclude = ['company']
```

Where the model looks like this:

```
class CompanyAnnouncement(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['publish_datetime']
        verbose_name = 'Company Announcement'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Company Announcements'

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish_datetime = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=6, max_digits=18, help_text='Leave blank to publish immediately')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='company_announcements', help_text='', null=True, blank=True)
```

I have overridden the default input widget for the publish_datetime to use a DateTimeInput, in spite of the value being a decimal. This is because I want the users to input a datetime, and then convert it to unix time before saving it in the db. This is done in the view:

```
class AccouncementCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    form_class = AnnouncementCreationForm
    template_name = 'create_announcement.html'
    redirect_unauthenticated_users = True
    success_url = '/users/my_companies'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.company = Company.objects.filter(crn=self.kwargs['company_spec_url'])[0]
        print(type(form.instance.publish_datetime)) # Returns 'datetime.datetime'
        if form.instance.publish_datetime:
            form.instance.publish_datetime = form.instance.publish_datetime.timestamp()
        else:
            form.instance.publish_datetime = dt.now().timestamp()
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The latter half of the if statement (i.e. the input field is blank) works, and it successfully stores the current unix time in the db, but the first half does not work. The form complains, saying 'please input a number', suggesting that it takes its validation from the model definition, rather than from the input widget definition. How do I make it validate the datetimeinput widget as a normal datetime, before letting the conversion happen in the view before `form.save()`?

Comment: The widgets don't perform validations. You should use the `clean` method in your form. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean

Comment: @guillermochamorro So I should do the conversion (the if statement above) in the model, not in the view?

Comment: I see you made a new question. I put the wrong link here because I meant the `clean` method in the `ModelForm` rather than the `Model`.